# PHP possible header redirection exploit?

Tags: php

I was thinking the other day, if someone is protecting their pages like this :

```
if(!$logged_in)
    {
        header("Location:http://mysite/login.php");
    }

    // protected content here
```

is there any way to ignore the HTTP Header redirect at the browser level and then display the protected content that follows it ?

Comment: You should quit processing at that point anyway... no need to fetch, crunch and display data if you'll never show it to the user anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, because using the header() function merely sets a header. The server will continue running the rest of the PHP script, rendering the protected content

You'll want to do this instead

```
if(!$logged_in)
    {
        header("Location:http://mysite/login.php");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: but how do you ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Any headers can be ignored.

You should kill the page exit() right after you redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but the advised procedure is to follow the header with the line:

```
if(!$logged_in)
    {
        header("Location:http://mysite/login.php");
exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you output data and your users ignore the header redirect (non-standard browser) - yes.